# notepad++ select text until catch a specifc character

Tags: select, text, expression, notepad++

I have a text like this

```
ROW0_ccTag=AA+AA&ysco=45aa&ROW0_ccHandle=123456789123&
```

I want to select those

```
_ccTag=AA+AA&
_ccHandle=123456789123&
```

I tried this expression

```
\_ccTag\=.+
```

but it's selecting the whole text until the last &
I want to select until the first & catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have an end point and the lazy operator:

```
\_ccTag\=.+?\&
```

https://regex101.com/r/jY3qN7/1

Comment: This doesn't select either the first or second line he lists

Comment: As @Gerrat , How to select both of them with 1 search

Comment: Do you mean via capturing groups?

Comment: I was wrong this did match the `first line` (not sure why this didn't work for me when I tested it).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (included an `|` alternate match):

```
\_ccTag=.+?\&|\_ccHandle\=.+?\&
```

Comment: Thanks indeed it worked , but How I could replace thorough this like change the text after tag to aaa and after the handle to bbb . it worked in searching but not replacing

Comment: I used `\_ccTag=aaa\&|\_ccHandle\=bbb\&` in the replace with but didn't work . it repacled every value with the whole replacing with line

Comment: @EduardoMejias: If you're replacing part then you don't want to match the entire part, you want to match the part you're replacing.

Comment: If you are trying to do more than search you really need to come up with more specifics. As is, the question is very unclear.