# Notepad ++: selecting text up to matched characters

Tags: regex, select, text, notepad++, match

In notepad ++, I want to select text up to a certain text match, including the match.

The txt file I am working with contains a lot of text with also white characters, returns and some special characters. In this text, there are characters that mark an end. Let's call these stop characters "ZZ." for now.

Using RegEx, I tried to create an expression that finds the next "ZZ." and selects everything before it. This is what it looks like:

+., \c ZZ.\n

But I seem to have gotten something wrong. As it is a similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635915/notepad-select-text-until-catch-a-specifc-character)
problem, I tried to use their RegEx with slight modification. Here is a picture so you can figure what I'd like to accomplish:
[image]
Find the next stop marker, selext the marker and everything before it.

In the actual file, the stop marker is "გვ."
If I want to use those, maybe I need to change the RegEx even more, as those are no ASCII characters? Like so, as stated in the [RegEx Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Non_ASCII_characters)?

\c+ (\x{nnnn}\x{nnnn}.)\n

Not quite sure if the \c works that way. I have seen expressions that use something like (A-Za-z)(0-9) but this is a different alphabet.

Comment: It is not clear, but if you need to match any text before and including `ZZ.` use `.*?ZZ\.` or `(?s).*?ZZ\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any text up to and including some pattern, use `.*?` (to match any zero or more characters, as few as possible) with the *`.` matches newline* option ON and add the  `გვ` after it:

[image]

Comment: `.*?გვ` has worked, however it only selects one line.

`(?s).*?გვ\.` has worked better!

Comment: Is *`.` matches newline* checked? Once it is checked, the `.` matches any character *including* a newline.

Comment: It is, and `(?s).*?გვ\.` works just as intended. Ty.

Comment: The point about `(?s` *inline DOTALL modifier* is that it overrides the UI *`.` matches newline* setting. If `(?s)` is present, that option is considered ON.

Comment: Oh, I see. (?s) will work the same in every other RegEx as well I suppose

Comment: In NPP, yes. In other PCRE, .NET, Java, Python, Boost, Oniguruma/Omigmo, ICU regexps, too.